# Anyway to specify the type of report on .coveragerc?

Tags: xml, pytest, coverage.py

I'm trying to move as much as I can the configuration of pytest-cov on **.coveragerc**

I need to replicate the **--cov-report xml** argument passed on the command line inside the file.

I tried to use **[xml]** tag and **output = whatever**, then i found **outfile** and i used that one as well, but still the report is not streamed to a xml file.

Anyone did have the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify the type of report in the .coveragerc file.  If you want to stop using pytest-cov, then you need two commands: one to run the tests under coverage, and one to generate the report:

```
$ coverage run -m py.test etc etc
$ coverage xml
```

Comment: I will have keep my solution then

py.test --cov $(MOD_NAME) --cov-config .coveragerc --cov-report xml --junit-xml=results.xml
with coveragerc  containing exclusions

Thank you